# Best Socks Proxy for MobileFirst iOS Push Dispatcher RHEL6

Tags: proxy, ibm-mobilefirst, socks, rhel6

MobileFirst Server 7.1 
WebSphere 8.5 
IBM HTTP Server
OS RHEL 6

We have our WepSphere application server in a private network and using IHS web server in a public network to allow access to the applications deployed.

To implement push notification for iOS, We need to setup a SOCKS proxy on our public network which allows MobileFirst server on the private network to send the push notification.

APNS uses UDP / TCP socket communication. To enable, I can create an SSH proxy request from WAS to WEB server, that will create a tunnel. But it's not recommended for production use.

Is there any recommended socks proxy server for RHEL 6 which seamlessly works with MobileFirst iOS Push dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your direct question - no, there is not a SOCKS proxy that IBM specifically recommends for use with the MobileFirst Platform.  SOCKS is a protocol, not a software package, so any package (or, perhaps, a hardware firewall appliance) that correctly implements the SOCKS protocol should be fine.

However, that being said - you might try [Dante](https://www.inet.no/dante/) to see if it meets your needs as a SOCKS proxy.  I've never used it myself, and I can't give it any specific endorsement.  I only suggest looking at it because it's free, and it is provided with pre-built binaries that work on RHEL 6.2 (or you could just build it from source, if you want).

In [this blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/10/configure-push-notification-proxy/), an IBM L3 support engineer describes how to set up a SOCKS proxy using SSH, but that might not be practical to use in production.

Comment: Hi Pat, Thanks. I have installed and configured Dante socks proxy on my WEB server and updated the JNID property of MobileFirst runtime with the Proxy IP and Port. Is there any way to test the SOCKS proxy is working with MobileFirst runtime installed on WAS deployed in a PRIVATE VLAN.

Comment: As long as the SOCKS server has connectivity to both the private VLAN (where the MobileFirst runtime is deployed) and the public Internet, you can test it just by using it.  I guess I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.